# Share gifts with FB SDK iOS

Tags: share, response, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am having a problem making gifts (pack of coins, lives, etc). I have been using [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests).

I think I did everything correctly at https://developers.facebook.com/, created the coin type, made the object and used its id. 
This is my code for request:

```
FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];
gameRequestContent.message = @"Take this coins";
gameRequestContent.title = @"Choose users";
gameRequestContent.filters = FBSDKGameRequestFilterAppUsers;
gameRequestContent.actionType = FBSDKGameRequestActionTypeSend;
gameRequestContent.objectID = @"386681778192859";
[FBSDKGameRequestDialog showWithContent:gameRequestContent delegate:self];
```

My question is how I can take a message or a callback from this request at another device. I was looking for a solution at facebook site, but I didn't find anything. In general, is it possible or do I have to make custom server?

Comment: Hey! have you sorted out this issue? I'm stuck on the same thing :/ thanks